# CSS and test alignment after picture thumbnail

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rbgobvgb/1/) is my fiddle.

As you can see here:

[image]

My issue is that I would always like the text to be below the thumbnail not to the right.  On the desktop site it is fine but on the mobile site the shorter titles appear on the right of the picture. Below is my relevant CSS, with all code on my fiddle. How do I go about doing this elegantly, avoiding !important and other taboo things if possible.  But to be honest I am so frustrated at this point I just want it fixed...

```
h2 {
    color: #191A1E;
    font-family: Open Sans,Arial,sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 21px;
}

.su-post-meta {display:none;}

.su-post-title a {
    margin-top: 15px !important;
    float: left;
    color: #191A1E;
}

.su-posts-default-loop .su-post-thumbnail {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.su-posts-default-loop .su-post-thumbnail img {
    max-width: 225px;
    max-height: 152px;
}
.su-posts-default-loop h2.su-post-title {
    clear: none;
    margin: 0 0 0.3em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.su-posts-default-loop .su-post-meta {
    margin-bottom: 0.7em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
.su-posts-teaser-loop .su-post:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you give `float:left` to `.su-post-title a` and  `.su-posts-default-loop .su-post-thumbnail` Just remove it. It will solved your problem.

Your updated css:

```
h2 {
    color: #191A1E;
    font-family: Open Sans,Arial,sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 21px;
}

.su-post-meta {display:none;}

.su-post-title a {
    margin-top: 15px !important;
    color: #191A1E;
}

.su-posts-default-loop .su-post-thumbnail {

    display: block;
    margin-right: 1em;
}






.su-posts-default-loop .su-post-thumbnail img {
    max-width: 225px;
    max-height: 152px;
}
.su-posts-default-loop h2.su-post-title {
    clear: none;
    margin: 0 0 0.3em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.su-posts-default-loop .su-post-meta {
    margin-bottom: 0.7em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
.su-posts-teaser-loop .su-post:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/rbgobvgb/7/)

Comment: This fixed my issue, thank you so much! +1 and accepting answer.  Out of curiosity how could I have better solved my own issue.  I am obviously still learning CSS but do you have any pointers on how I could have tracked this down on my own, or is it just experience?

Comment: WC. glad to help. actually one thing is experience and you should use developer tools like firebug and also required search for your issue to learn.

Comment: Yeah I have tried to search google and tried several different alignment techniques.  No luck... I have been using the developer tools in chrome to at least narrow down what CSS is effecting my elements. I can usually get it but I think because there were two classes that needed to be changed it was beyond me.   I will check out firebug thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Remove `float:left` on `.su-posts-default-loop .su-post-thumbnail`  and add to  `.su-post`

```
.su-posts-default-loop .su-post-thumbnail {     
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.su-post{
float:left;   

}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/rbgobvgb/6/)**